# Get proper position/resolution for SpriteKit game

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, position

I've got a very tedious issue. I'm playing around with Swift and trying to make a basic game, except i want to position sprites randomly across the width of the screen. Also, I want to position some labels such as the running score in the top left/right part of the screen.

The trouble is when I get the values of the scenes frame I get 1024, 768 on an iPhone 5 Simulator, and I can't seem to find a way to get the real height/width of the screen so I can properly position everything.

Hopefully it's something simple I just haven't worked out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Check this method for getting center and adjust them  yourLabel.position =        `CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)                                        CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));`
OR Try 
For a label in the top left corner:

```
label.horizontalAlignmentMode = .Left
label.position = CGPoint(x:0.0, y:self.size.height)
```

Or for the top right:

```
label.horizontalAlignmentMode = .Right
label.position = CGPoint(x:self.size.width, y:self.size.height)
```

I Hope that helps.:)

Comment: Thanks for the help.

The top one works, to make it central. But when I try top left/right as you just said nothing appears.

Comment: No problem try  CGRectGetMinX(<#CGRect rect#>) top left x and  CGRectGetMinY(<#CGRect rect#>) and Y    ,this should be top left coordinates relative to your view. I hope it fixed the problem :)!